# Create dynamic grid layout for Bus Seating

Tags: android, layout, dynamic

I have needed to create bus seat view layout according to response.
I have used RecyclerView with grid layout but unable to get it.
So please help me to create this type of layout dynamically according to response.

> Response

```
[
   {
       "column": "4",
       "length": "1",
       "name": "9",
       "row": "1",
       "width": "1"
     },
     {
       "column": "3",
       "length": "1",
       "name": "8",
       "row": "0",
       "width": "1"
     },
     {
       "column": "3",
       "length": "1",
       "name": "7",
       "row": "1",
       "width": "1"
     },
    {
       "column": "2",
       "length": "1",
       "name": "6",
       "row": "0",
       "width": "1"
     },
     {
       "column": "2",
       "length": "1",
       "name": "5",
       "row": "1",
       "width": "1"
     },
     {
       "column": "1",
       "length": "1",
       "name": "4",
       "row": "0",
       "width": "1"
     },
     {
       "column": "1",
       "length": "1",
       "name": "3",
       "row": "1",
       "width": "1"
     },
     {
       "column": "0",
       "length": "1",
       "name": "2",
       "row": "0",
       "width": "1"
     },
     {
       "column": "0",
       "length": "1",
       "name": "1",
       "row": "1",
       "width": "1"
     },
     {
       "column": "8",
       "length": "2",
       "name": "L9",
       "row": "1",
       "width": "1"
     },
     {
       "column": "10",
       "length": "2",
       "name": "L11",
       "row": "1",
       "width": "1"
     },
     {
       "column": "6",
       "length": "2",
       "name": "L8",
       "row": "0",
       "width": "1"
     },
     {
       "column": "10",
       "length": "2",
       "name": "L12",
       "row": "0",
       "width": "1"
     },
     {
       "column": "6",
       "length": "2",
       "name": "L7",
       "row": "1",
       "width": "1"
     },
     {
       "column": "10",
       "length": "2",
       "name": "L6",
       "row": "3",
       "width": "1"
     },
     {
       "column": "8",
       "length": "2",
       "name": "L10",
       "row": "0",
       "width": "1"
     },
     {
       "column": "8",
       "length": "2",
       "name": "L5",
       "row": "3",
       "width": "1"
     },
     {
       "column": "6",
       "length": "2",
       "name": "L4",
       "row": "3",
       "width": "1"
     },
     {
       "column": "4",
       "length": "2",
       "name": "L3",
       "row": "3",
       "width": "1"
     },
     {
       "column": "2",
       "length": "2",
       "name": "L2",
       "row": "3",
       "width": "1"
     },
     {
       "column": "0",
       "length": "2",
       "name": "L1",
       "row": "3",
       "width": "1"
     },
     {
       "column": "5",
       "length": "1",
       "name": "12",
       "row": "0",
       "width": "1"
     },
     {
       "column": "5",
       "length": "1",
       "name": "11",
       "row": "1",
       "width": "1"
     },
     {
       "column": "4",
       "length": "1",
       "name": "10",
       "row": "0",
       "width": "1"
     }
]
```

**Here length and width means span in grid. And screen added for more understand.**

> Screen Layout

[image]

> Screen Layout with seat no

[image]

Please help me to create this type of layout according to response.
Thanks.

Comment: https://github.com/TakeoffAndroid/SeatBookingRecyclerView

Comment: Its not as i want. I needed to response wise if length is 2 then it consume 2 cells

Comment: I think that you will have to draw that view manually (create your custom view)

Comment: I know that i needed to create dynamic view but have any idea to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

you can make this seat arrangement with the help of tableLayout in android very easily!!

for example -

check this json for row 4 and column 7 -

```
data class BusJson(
    val colmn : Int,
    val row : Int,
    val type : String,
    val name : String,
    val price : Int,
    val isPaymentDone : Boolean,
    val deckType : String
)



object allBusItem {


    fun busSeatJason(): MutableList<BusJson> {
        return mutableListOf(
            //first row seat
            BusJson(
                colmn = 5, row = 0, type = "S", name = "A1" , price = 75 , isPaymentDone = false , deckType  = "Upper Deck"
            ),
            BusJson(
                colmn = 4, row = 0, type = "N", name = "A2", price = 129 , isPaymentDone = false, deckType  = "Upper Deck"
            ),
            BusJson(
                colmn = 6, row = 0, type = "S", name = "A3" , price = 51 , isPaymentDone = false, deckType  = "Upper Deck"
            ),
            BusJson(
                colmn = 0, row = 0, type = "N", name = "A4" ,  price = 131 , isPaymentDone = false, deckType  = "Upper Deck"
            ),
            BusJson(
                colmn = 3, row = 0, type = "N", name = "A5" ,  price = 121 , isPaymentDone = false, deckType  = "Upper Deck"
            ),
            BusJson(
                colmn = 2, row = 0, type = "   ", name = "Null" , price = 0 , isPaymentDone = false, deckType  = "Upper Deck"
            ),
            BusJson(
                colmn = 1, row = 0, type = "   ", name = "Null" , price = 0 , isPaymentDone = false, deckType  = "Upper Deck"
            ),

            //Second row seat
            BusJson(
                colmn = 0, row = 1, type = "N", name = "A10", price = 141 , isPaymentDone = false, deckType  = "Upper Deck"
            ),
            BusJson(
                colmn = 1, row = 1, type = "N", name = "A20"  , price = 181 , isPaymentDone = false, deckType  = "Upper Deck"
            ),
            BusJson(
                colmn = 2, row = 1, type = "S", name = "A30", price = 21 , isPaymentDone = false, deckType  = "Upper Deck"
            ),
            BusJson(
                colmn = 3, row = 1, type = "N", name = "A40", price = 195 , isPaymentDone = false, deckType  = "Upper Deck"
            ),
            BusJson(
                colmn = 4, row = 1, type = "N", name = "A50", price = 139 , isPaymentDone = false, deckType  = "Upper Deck"
            ),
            BusJson(
                colmn = 5, row = 1, type = "   ", name = "Null" , price = 0 , isPaymentDone = false, deckType  = "Upper Deck"
            ),
            BusJson(
                colmn = 6, row = 1, type = "   ", name = "Null" , price = 0 , isPaymentDone = false, deckType  = "Upper Deck"
            ),

            //Third row seat
            BusJson(
                colmn = 0, row = 2, type = "   ", name = "Null" , price = 0 , isPaymentDone = false, deckType  = "Upper Deck"
            ),
            BusJson(
                colmn = 1, row = 2, type = "   ", name = "Null", price = 0 , isPaymentDone = false, deckType  = "Upper Deck"
            ),
            BusJson(
                colmn = 2, row = 2, type = "   ", name = "Null" , price = 0 , isPaymentDone = false, deckType  = "Upper Deck"
            ),
            BusJson(
                colmn = 3, row = 2, type = "   ", name = "Null" , price = 0 , isPaymentDone = false, deckType  = "Upper Deck"
            ),
            BusJson(
                colmn = 4, row = 2, type = "   ", name = "Null" , price = 0 , isPaymentDone = false, deckType  = "Upper Deck"
            ),
            BusJson(
                colmn = 5, row = 2, type = "   ", name = "Null" , price = 0 , isPaymentDone = false, deckType  = "Upper Deck"
            ),
            BusJson(
                colmn = 6, row = 2, type = "   ", name = "Null" , price = 0 , isPaymentDone = false, deckType  = "Upper Deck"
            ),


            //Forth row seat
            BusJson(
                colmn = 5, row = 3, type = "N", name = "A11" , price = 161 , isPaymentDone = false, deckType  = "Upper Deck"
            ),
            BusJson(
                colmn = 3, row = 3, type = "N", name = "A22" , price = 151 , isPaymentDone = false, deckType  = "Upper Deck"
            ),
            BusJson(
                colmn = 4, row = 3, type = "S", name = "A33" , price = 36 , isPaymentDone = false, deckType  = "Upper Deck"
            ),
            BusJson(
                colmn = 2, row = 3, type = "   ", name = "Null" , price = 0 , isPaymentDone = false, deckType  = "Upper Deck"
            ),
            BusJson(
                colmn = 1, row = 3, type = "   ", name = "Null" , price = 0 , isPaymentDone = false, deckType  = "Upper Deck"
            ),
            BusJson(
                colmn = 0, row = 3, type = "S", name = "A44", price = 49 , isPaymentDone = false, deckType  = "Upper Deck"
            ),
            BusJson(
                colmn = 6, row = 3, type = "N", name = "A55" , price = 129 , isPaymentDone = false, deckType  = "Upper Deck"
            ),
        )
    }

}
```

and then design it in empty paper as a 2d matrix !

it is a  my java class for tableLayout , for implementing above list

```
tableLayout = findViewById(R.id.upperDTable)
        tableLayoutTwo = findViewById(R.id.LowerDeckTable)
        mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.RecyclerViewID)
        mButton = findViewById(R.id.Pay)
        mTotal = findViewById(R.id.totalPrice)


        mRecyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        val seatSelectedData = ArrayList<busSeatModel>()



        val tableItems = allBusItem.busSeatJason()
        val tableItemsLower = allBusItemForLower.busSeatJasonLower()



// Assuming numRows and numCols are the dimensions of your table
        val numRows = 4
        val numCols = 7

        for (i in 0 until numRows) {
            val tableRow = TableRow(this)
            tableRow.layoutParams = TableRow.LayoutParams(
                TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
            )

            for (j in 0 until numCols) {
                val cell = ImageView(this)
                cell.setImageDrawable(resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.baseline_chair_24))
                cell.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8)

                val rowParams = TableRow.LayoutParams(
                    0,
                    TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    1.0f
                )

                cell.layoutParams = rowParams
                tableRow.addView(cell)
            }

            tableLayout.addView(tableRow)
        }

        val imageView = ImageView(this)
        val params = TableRow.LayoutParams(25, 25) // Set width and height here
        imageView.layoutParams = params

        for( i in 0 until tableItems.size){

            if(tableItems[i].type == "N"){
                imageView.setImageDrawable(resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.images2,null))
            }
            else if(tableItems[i].type == "S"){
                imageView.setImageDrawable(resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.images,null))
            }
        (tableLayout.getChildAt(tableItems[i].row) as TableRow).getChildAt(tableItems[i].colmn).let {
            if (it is ImageView) {
                val params = TableRow.LayoutParams(100, 100) // Set width and height here
                it.layoutParams = params

                if(tableItems[i].type == "N"){
                    it.setImageDrawable(resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.images2,null))

                    it.setOnClickListener {
                        if (seatSelectedData.size < 3) {
                            Toast.makeText(
                                this,
                                "Normal ${tableItems[i].name} Seat Price is ${tableItems[i].price}",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                            ).show()
                            totalPrice += tableItems[i].price
                            mTotal.text = "Total Price - ${totalPrice.toString()} "

                            seatSelectedData.add(
                                busSeatModel(
                                    tableItems[i].name,
                                    tableItems[i].price.toString(),
                                    "${tableItems[i].type}ormal Seat",
                                    tableItems[i].deckType
                                    )
                            )
                            val adapter = BusSeatAdaptor(this, seatSelectedData)
                            mRecyclerView.adapter = adapter
                        }
                        else{
                            Toast.makeText(
                                this,
                                " maximum 3 seats are only booked at that time",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                            ).show()
                        }
                    }
                }
                else if(tableItems[i].type == "S"){
                    it.setImageDrawable(resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.images,null))

                    it.setOnClickListener {
                        if (seatSelectedData.size < 3) {

                            Toast.makeText(
                                this,
                                "Shared ${tableItems[i].name} Seat Price is ${tableItems[i].price}",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                            ).show()

                            totalPrice += tableItems[i].price
                            mTotal.text = "Total Price - ${totalPrice.toString()} "


                            seatSelectedData.add(
                                busSeatModel(
                                    tableItems[i].name,
                                    tableItems[i].price.toString(),
                                    "${tableItems[i].type}hared Seat",
                                    tableItems[i].deckType
                                    )
                            )
                            val adapter = BusSeatAdaptor(this, seatSelectedData)
                            mRecyclerView.adapter = adapter
                        }
                        else{
                            Toast.makeText(
                                this,
                                " maximum 3 seats are only booked at that time",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                            ).show()
                        }
                    }
                }

              }
           }
        }
```